# Browse local directory and files in a Django View

Tags: python, django

I'm developing a Django project and I have the following "problem".
I have a local directory that has subdirectories, in which I got some PDF files. For example:

Main Dir:

```
|-->2000
____|-->A
________|-->file1.pdf
________|-->file2.pdf
____|-->B
________|-->file3.pdf
____|-->C
________|-->...
____|-->D
________|-->...
|-->2001
___|--> ...
|-->2002
___|--> ...
```

All the folders contain thousands of PDF files.

I want to display this directory in a Django view and let the user browse it by clicking the subdirectories and the PDF files so he can view them in his browser and maybe even add a "Download PDF" button. I also want to format it a bit, maybe add a search function too in the future if possible.

It is my first time working with local files and Django so I'm a bit lost.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: This is a bit broad. You need to show what you have tried and what didn't work.

Comment: removed the totally unrelated "pdf" and "web-deployment" tags...

Comment: I haven't tried much to be honest. I'm still planning on how to make this work and I thought I'd use some help to do it the right way since I am a complete amateur. I was thinking of using the os.listdir method to get the directories and move through that by presenting the results into a template, then make the directories "clickable" and move deeper etc.

Answer (score 2):

You could use ListView like this

```
class FileObject():

    name = ''

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

class DirListView(ListView):

    template_name = 'main/list_dir.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        files = []
        for filename in os.listdir(path):
            fileobject = FileObject(name=filename)
            files.append(fileobject)
        return files
```

This ListView the could be used like any other ListView. Not sure about the permission and locations about path. This must be steared by settings.py I guess

Comment: Thank you for the idea, I'll give it a go, looks very easy and doable! I'll comeback with the results soon :D